# Increasing the speed of reading a csv file C++

Tags: c++, csv, io

I created this code to read and filter my csv files.
It works like I want it to work for small files.
But I just tried out a file of size 200k lines and it takes around 4 minutes, which is too long for my use case.

After testing a bit and fixing some quite stupid things I got the time down a little to 3 minutes.
I found out about half of the Time is spent reading in the file and half of the Time is spend generating the Result Vector.

Is there any way to Improve the speed of my Programm?
Especially the Reading from csv part?
I do not really have an Idea at the moment.
I'd appreciate any help.

EDIT:The filter is filtering the data by either a timeframe or timeframe and filterword in specific columns and outputting the data into a resulting vector of strings.

My CSV files look like this->

Headers are:

```
ID;Timestamp;ObjectID;UserID;Area;Description;Comment;Checksum
```

Data is:

```
523;19.05.2021 12:15;####;admin;global;Parameter changed to xxx; Comment;x3J2j4
```

```cpp
std::ifstream input_file(strComplPath, std::ios::in);

int counter = 0;
while (std::getline(input_file, record))
{
    istringstream line(record);
    while (std::getline(line, record, delimiter))
    {
        record.erase(remove(record.begin(), record.end(), '\"'), record.end());
        items.push_back(record);
        //cout << record;
    }

    csv_contents[counter] = items;
    items.clear();
    ++counter;
}
 

for (int i = 0; i < csv_contents.size(); i++) {
    string regexline = csv_contents[i][1];
    string endtime = time_upper_bound;
    string starttime = time_lower_bound;
    bool checkline = false;
    bool isInRange = false, isLater = false, isEarlier = false;

    // Check for faulty Data and replace it with an empty string 
    for (int oo = 0; oo < 8; oo++) {
        if (csv_contents[i][oo].rfind("#", 0) == 0) {
            csv_contents[i][oo] = "";
        }
    }

    if ((regex_search(starttime, m, timestampformat) && regex_search(endtime, m, timestampformat))) {
        filtertimeboth = true;
    }
    else if (regex_search(starttime, m, timestampformat)) {
        filterfromstart = true;
    }
    else if (regex_search(endtime, m, timestampformat)) {
        filtertoend = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should try to describe your problem more clearly, and also share minimum reproducible code, not just dump all of your code and expect us to read through and try to understand what you are attempting[especially when code is this lengthy :-) ] , see about [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Did you try running valgrind on it to see which funtions take a lot of time? Just from the code I suspect `regex_search` to be pretty slow

Comment: Your code is lacking `isDateInRange`, `isDateLater` and `isDateEarlier` too. One problem with having almost everything in one big function is that it becomes complicated to isolate and debug/enhance particualar pieces of the program. I suggest that you create a `class` that holds the fields for one record in your CSV file.

Comment: It'd also help if you gave actual names to all the fields in the CSV file. It'll make it a lot easier to understand. Also, describe what the filter is supposed to do.

Comment: @dave Is there any alternative to testing if my Input string of Date and time is valid?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I added the actual names. The Date function are only a small calculation with little if else. So i thought id leave them out

Comment: `csv_contents[counter] = items;` -> `csv_contents[counter] = std::move(items);` would avoid a copy, In the same way: `items.push_back(std::move(record));`.

Comment: Use a database library.

Comment: In order to speed up your code, you'll need to understand how hard drives work.  In order to read, they need to power up, locate your file, seek to the appropriate location, then read the data you requested. The actions before reading are the overhead.  The overhead applies to every transaction (except for cached versions).  So, ideally, you'll want to keep the drive spinning, a.k.a. keep reading from the drive for the best performance.  Read large quantities into memory rather than many transactions of small length.

Comment: The second speed block is formatting or extracting the data from the file (or from memory).  Fixed length records are a lot more efficient, each field starts on the same column, so you can determine field positions using math.  However CSV are more often variable length records.  You'll need to read data until a comma is found.  If you need to use newlines as record separators, you may need to search for the newline before extracting fields.  This is using up (wasting more time).  Again, fixed length records can reduce this.

Comment: IMHO, there is a limit to the optimization you can achieve reading a CSV file.  The CSV file format is not designed for efficiency.  If you need more efficiency, use a different file format or use a database.  Databases are optimized for data transactions.

Comment: I see some candidates like the istringstream creation and use of regex's on every line. Still it could be that these are totally dominated by file I/O. One need to profile this to get the heaviest candidate. Profilers might miss I/O so classic timing (with high precision) is okay here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what the bottleneck is in your program (I copied your code from an earlier version of the question) but you have a lot of regex:es and mix reading records with post processing. I suggest that you create a `class` to hold one of these records, called `record`, overload `operator>>` for `record` and then use `std::copy_if` from the file with a filter that you can design separately from the reading. Do post processing *after* you've read the records that passes the filter.

I made a small test and it takes 2 seconds to read 200k records on my old spinning disk while doing filtering. I only used `time_lower_bound` and `time_upper_bound` to filter and additional checks will of course make it a little slower, but it should not take *minutes*.

Example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

// the suggested class to hold a record
struct record {
    int ID;
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point Timestamp;
    std::string ObjectID;
    std::string UserID;
    std::string Area;
    std::string Description;
    std::string Comment;
    std::string Checksum;
};
```

```
// A free function to read a time_point from an `istream`:
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point to_tp(std::istream& is, const char* fmt) {
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp{};
    // C++20:
    // std::chrono::from_stream(is, tp, fmt, nullptr, nullptr);

    // C++11 to C++17 version:
    std::tm tmtp{};
    tmtp.tm_isdst = -1;
    if(is >> std::get_time(&tmtp, fmt)) {
        tp = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(&tmtp));
    }
    return tp;
}
```

```
// The operator>> overload to read one `record` from an `istream`:
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, record& r) {
    is >> r.ID;
    r.Timestamp = to_tp(is, ";%d.%m.%Y %H:%M;"); // using the helper function above
    std::getline(is, r.ObjectID, ';');
    std::getline(is, r.UserID, ';');
    std::getline(is, r.Area, ';');
    std::getline(is, r.Description, ';');
    std::getline(is, r.Comment, ';');
    std::getline(is, r.Checksum);
    return is;
}
```

```
// An operator<< overload to print one `record`:
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const record& r) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << r.ID;
    { // I only made a C++11 to C++17 version for this one:
        std::time_t time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(r.Timestamp);
        std::tm ts = *std::localtime(&time);
        oss << ';' << ts.tm_mday << '.' << ts.tm_mon + 1 << '.'
            << ts.tm_year + 1900 << ' ' << ts.tm_hour << ':' << ts.tm_min << ';';
    }
    oss << r.ObjectID << ';' << r.UserID << ';' << r.Area << ';'
        << r.Description << ';' << r.Comment << ';' << r.Checksum << '\n';
    return os << oss.str();
}
```

```
// The reading and filtering part of `main` would then look like this:
int main() { // not "void main()"
    std::istringstream time_lower_bound_s("20.05.2019 16:40:00");
    std::istringstream time_upper_bound_s("20.05.2021 09:40:00");

    // Your time boundaries as `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`s - 
    // again using the `to_tp` helper function:
    auto time_lower_bound = to_tp(time_lower_bound_s, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S");
    auto time_upper_bound = to_tp(time_upper_bound_s, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S");

    // Verify that the boundaries were parsed ok:
    if(time_lower_bound == std::chrono::system_clock::time_point{} ||
       time_upper_bound == std::chrono::system_clock::time_point{}) {
        std::cerr << "failed to parse boundaries\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::ifstream is("data"); // whatever your file is called
    if(is) {
        std::vector<record> recs; // a vector with all the records

        // create your filter
        auto filter = [&time_lower_bound, &time_upper_bound](const record& r) {
            // Only copy those `record`s within the set boundaries.
            // You can add additional conditions here too.
            return r.Timestamp >= time_lower_bound &&
                   r.Timestamp <= time_upper_bound;
        };

        // Copy those records that pass the filter:
        std::copy_if(std::istream_iterator<record>(is),
                     std::istream_iterator<record>{}, std::back_inserter(recs),
                     filter);

        // .. post process `recs` here ...

        // print result
        for(auto& r : recs) std::cout << r;
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help a lot! I just tried your solution which I can get to compile but not to get any output into the recs vector. I can see that there are Inputs from the ifstream. Now im wondering how copy actually works with ifstreams. Since the Input is the begin/end and the backinserter aswell as a condition for copy_if. But I cant get it to copy anything even as copy.

Comment: @DoItWithFlow  You're welcome! _"... which I can get to compile ..."_  - Did you need to make changes for it to compile? `clang++ -Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-padded` compiles it clean for me. `std::copy_if` has no idea it's a stream. That's what the `std::istream_iterator`s do. If you want, I can take a look at your implementation of my suggestions to see if I can see where the problem is. Put it at https://pastebin.com/ or similar and I'll check it out.

Comment: I did not have to make changes for it to compile. This pastebin is not my final implementation since the final one has alot of custom datatypes for conforming to SPS-Controller Standards.(No need to worry about that)   https://pastebin.com/wbMdyQpC

Comment: @DoItWithFlow Every change you make to the types in the `record` class will need a corresponding change to the `operator>>` overload. Since you changed `int ID` to `std::string RecordID;` you need to change `is >> RecordID;` to `std::getline(is, r.RecordID, ';');` which also have an effect on the format string on the next line: `r.Timestamp = to_tp(is, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M;");` (the initial `;` is removed) - I noticed that you added `"` around the timestamp in the format string, but those are not in the example data you provided so with those two changes, your `std::copy` copies _all_ the records

Comment: Oh well. I got it to work... Im sorry for the basic questions. But I had to find out that the ODK-Server Im using for some reason doesnt work with your solution(Unfortunatly there is little documentation about the ODK-Server). I got it fully working for console output but as soon as i implemented the dll, the ODK-Server gives me an Exception on execution.. I have to dig into that problem and otherwise find a different way... I hope you have a nice day.

Comment: @DoItWithFlow No problem. Now you have to revisit the logic. It' not necessarily spot on.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is already given by Ted. I made a solution in the same time. So let me show it additionally.

I created test data with 500k records and all parsing an stuff was done in below 3 seconds on my machine.

Additionally, I also created classes.

Speed will be gained by using `std::move`, increasing the input buffer size and using `reserve`for the `std::vector`.

Please see yet another solution below. I omitted filtering. Ted showed it already.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

constexpr size_t MaxLines = 600'000u;
constexpr size_t NumberOfLines = 500'000u;
const std::string fileName{ "test.csv" };

// Dummy rtoutine for writing a test file
void createFile() {
    if (std::ofstream ofs{ fileName }; ofs) {
        std::time_t ttt = 0;
        for (size_t k = 0; k < NumberOfLines; ++k) {
            std::time_t time = static_cast<time_t>(ttt);
            ttt += 1000;
            ofs << k << ';'
#pragma warning(suppress : 4996)
                << std::put_time(std::localtime(&time), "%d.%m.%Y  %H:%M") << ';'
                << k << ';'
                << "UserID" << k << ';'
                << "Area" << k << ';'
                << "Description" << k << ';'
                << "Comment" << k << ';'
                << "Checksum" << k << '\n';
        }
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Could not open '" << fileName << "' for writing\n\n";
}


// We will create a bigger input buffer for our stream
constexpr size_t ifStreamBufferSize = 100'000u;
static char buffer[ifStreamBufferSize];


// Object oriented Model. Class for one record
struct Record {

    // Data
    long id{};
    std::tm time{};
    long objectId{};
    std::string userId{};
    std::string area{};
    std::string description{};
    std::string comment{};
    std::string checkSum{};

    // Methods
    // Extractor operator
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Record& r) {

        // Read one complete line
        if (std::string line; std::getline(is, line)) {

            // Here we will stor the parts of the line after the split
            std::vector<std::string> parts{};

            // Convert line to istringstream for further extraction of line parts
            std::istringstream iss{ line };

            // One part of a line
            std::string part{};
            bool wrongData = false;

            // Split
            while (std::getline(iss, part, ';')) {

                // Check fpor error
                if (part[0] == '#') {
                    is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
                    break;
                }
                // add part
                parts.push_back(std::move(part));
            }
            // If all was OK
            if (is) {
                // If we have enough parts
                if (parts.size() == 8) {

                    // Convert parts to target data in record
                    r.id = std::strtol(parts[0].c_str(), nullptr, 10);

                    std::istringstream ss{parts[1]};
                    ss >> std::get_time(& r.time, "%d.%m.%Y  %H:%M");
                    if (ss.fail()) 
                        is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);

                    r.objectId = std::strtol(parts[2].c_str(), nullptr, 10);

                    r.userId = std::move(parts[3]);

                    r.area = std::move(parts[4]);

                    r.description = std::move(parts[5]);

                    r.comment = std::move(parts[6]);

                    r.checkSum = std::move(parts[7]);
                }
                else is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
            }
        }
        return is;
    }
    // Simple inserter function
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Record& r) {
        return os << r.id << "   "
#pragma warning(suppress : 4996)
            << std::put_time(&r.time, "%d.%m.%Y  %H:%M") << "   "  
            << r.objectId << "   " << r.userId << "   " << r.area << "   " << r.description << "   " << r.comment << "   " << r.checkSum;
    }
};

// Data will hold all records
struct Data {

    // Data part
    std::vector<Record> records{};

    // Constructor will reserve space to avaoid reallocation
    Data() { records.reserve(MaxLines); }

    // Simple extractor. Will call Record's exractor
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Data& d) {

        // Set bigger file buffer. This is a time saver
        is.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buffer, ifStreamBufferSize);
        std::copy(std::istream_iterator<Record>(is), {}, std::back_inserter(d.records));
        return is;
    }
    // Simple inserter
    friend std::ostream& operator >> (std::ostream& os, const Data& d) {
        std::copy(d.records.begin(), d.records.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Record>(os, "\n"));
        return os;
    }

};

int main() {
    // createFile();

    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start);

    if (std::ifstream ifs{ fileName }; ifs) {

        Data data;

        // Start time measurement
        start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

        // Read and parse complete data
        ifs >> data;

        // End of time measurement
        elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start);
        std::cout << "\nReading and splitting. Duration: " << elapsed.count() << " ms\n";

        // Some debug output
        std::cout << "\n\nNumber of read records:  " << data.records.size() << "\n\n";
        for (size_t k{}; k < 10; ++k)
            std::cout << data.records[k] << '\n';
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Could not open '" << fileName << "' for reading\n\n";
}
```

And yes, I used "ctime".

Comment: For you it is no rocket science. I really appreciate both of your solutions. I learned alot of new things from them. Appreciate the time you took for me!